# simple injector how to inject batch registered generic type into constructor

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Simple Injector newbie.

I've reviewed this documentation https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html to learn about how to work with generic types with simple injector.

I can't find in the documentation how to inject a class based on a generic type batch registration.

Here the documentation gives this example:

```
container.Register<IValidator<Customer>, CustomerValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Employee>, EmployeeValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Order>, OrderValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Product>, ProductValidator>();
```

can be registered like

```
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly);
```

But what datatype do you use in the constructor so that simple injector injects the right concrete datatype.

For example

```
public classaconstructor(IValidator<Order> vdator)
{
}
```

I was trying to find the right getinstance method from the documentation, but could not find it.
Thx.

Comment: Simple Injector, [by design](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#limited-batch-registration), has a [simple batch API](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-automatic-registration) - have you reviewed that topic already?

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed that documentation. It is unclear. I would have guessed that something like             
var a = container.GetInstance<IValidator<Order>>(); would work, but it does not

Comment: Well, you're using the container as a Service Locator, that way, which is really an anti-pattern. You don't need to explicitly do that for the constructor - that's taken care of by your dependency resolver. What type of project is this?

Comment: aspnet mvc. I thought dependencies are injected through the constructor.

Comment: Correct. You don't manually resolve those dependencies, though. You register Simple Injector as the DependencyResolver and then ASP.NET takes care of that. Have you done something similar to https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html - that last line is what I was referring to.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate why calling `GetInstance<IValidator<Order>>()` does not result in an `OrderValidator`? Please post error message and stack trace. If this is not what you are trying to achieve, please show *what* are are trying to achieve, for instamce by visualizing the object graph of classes you are trying to construct. If you would `new` and inject everything by hand (i.e. without Simple Injector), how would that code look?

Comment: yes, i have. that's the documentation i referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The batch registration API you're referring to, is just a function which scans the assembly for all *closed* implementations of `IValidator<T>`.

So assuming `IValidator<>` actually lives in the same assembly as `OrderValidator`, this call

```
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly);
```

will result in at least creating this registration:

```
container.Register<IValidator<Order>, OrderValidator>();
```

Which means that this simple unittest should pass:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RegisterIValidator_GetOrderValidatorInstanceSucceeds()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>),  typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly);

    container.Verify();

    var orderValidator = container.GetInstance<IValidator<Order>>();

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(orderValidator, typeof(OrderValidator));
}
```

Now when you want to use `OrderValidator` in some other class, you indeed ask for `IValidator<Order>` in the constructor as you did. That is the whole point of dependency injection and programming to abstractions.

Simple Injector will never silently fail or inject `null`. So if injections fails, there will be descriptive exception (with possible inner exceptions) telling you where to look.

My best guess, with the information provided, is that `OrderValidator` is living in another assembly. Notice that this overload does accept multiple assemblies.

If this is not the case, post the stacktrace, with inner exceptions as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So:
1. Is there some way of turning off simpleinjector throughout your program. Let's say you want to incrementally improve your code...over time... without simpleinjector trying to resolve every interface you have in a controller. In my project, it is trying to resolve all the interfaces in the scaffolding.

Comment: No, by calling `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));` you're telling MVC to let Simple Injector create the controllers. If you migrating it can be tedious to do so. You could in that case implement your own `DependencyResolver` in which you call into Simple Injector for the controllers done refactoring and fall back to default MVC for the rest

Comment: just trying to wrap my head around this code as well. so if the registration handles all the interface dependancies, when would you use container.GetInstance outside of testing?

Comment: @arod With MVC 'container.GetInstance' is not needed indeed. As a rule of thumb , application code should never call container.GetInstance.

Comment: So, how to I apply the proper registration for a closed interface type so I can compile this framework code?

this code from identityconfig.cs
 

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
 {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {}
       
Many thanks

Comment: Asp.net identity deserves a new question

Comment: Ok, I have done this, thx. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641953/using-simple-injector-with-aspnet-identity