# using simple injector with aspnet.identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, simple-injector

I'm trying to use simple injector with my mvc project, and I'm unclear how to complete all registrations for framework code. In particular, with this aspnet.identity code.In general, since this isn't my code and the call stack is through .net library .dlls, is there a way to get simpleinjector to work with this aspnet.identity code.

Examples:

In case below, I can see from subsequent code the the generic class that is instantiated from the generic interface, however I don't know how to register a generic interface that maps to a generic class, and whether or not if I completed this registration, if it would break code. But I cannot compile, if i'm using simpleinjector.

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {

    }
```

`
In the code below, I can see at runtime that authenticationManager is instantiated into Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager, but I can't even test if allowing simpleinjector to map the interface to that concrete type would break the code, since I can't compile this code, if i'm using simpleinjector.

```
public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }
```

thanks

**Update**
Hi, after things nicely compiled with the changes recommended I"m find that my emails from my account controller for registration and lost passwords are not going out. When I debug I find a different call stack for my branch containing simpleinjector. In this branch, the code in IdentityConfig.cs is not executed.

**Branch without simple injection / Email Reaching Correct Method in IdentityConfig.cs**

[image]

**Branch with simple injection / Emails Not Reaching Correct Method**
[image]

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597).

Comment: I followed the tutorial and received this error:
The constructor of type ApplicationSignInManager contains the parameter with name 'authenticationManager' and type IAuthenticationManager that is not registered. Please ensure IAuthenticationManager is registered, or change the constructor of ApplicationSignInManager.

Comment: Hi arod, I'm slowly moving parts of the original Codeplex discussion to Github. I now [added](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597#issuecomment-409811927) information about the `ApplicationSignInManager`.

Comment: @Steven -- I have found some issues with code flow after making the changes you advised. Many thanks

Comment: I updated the constructor to fix this:
public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
            userManager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            userManager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        }
@Steven, is this what you recommend?